# Windows Script to SSH into a Remote Server and Execute a Command

Tags: windows, shell, ssh, scripting, remote-execution

I'm looking to create a script that can be used on Windows by double-clicking it.

The script should connect via SSH to a specific port using a hard-coded password and then execute the command "pm2 restart 0."

How can I achieve this?

Samuel

I've already tried using Plink, but it doesn't seem to execute the command as expected. When I use Plink to connect to the remote server via SSH, it successfully establishes the connection, but it doesn't execute the desired 'pm2 restart 0' command. I'm looking for assistance in troubleshooting this issue and getting the command to run as intended.

Comment: _How can I achieve this?_ Here is how I would proceed: Since you tagged this _shell_  (1) I would decide which Windows implementation of sh I  want to use (i.e. Cygwin, WSL, ....) (2) I would install ssh (preferably an implementation which integrates well into my shell), and then (3) write the script.